# Facing a strange issue in modifying js file of a wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a wordpress woocommerce plugin named woocommerce-Request a quote plugin(dvin-wcql). I have to make some changes in its js file but the problem is that when I make any change in this file it works fine on localhost but it does not work on server rather the js script does not work. This is a strange issue I am facing in it.

//handles ajax call add to quotelist from product details page

function call_ajax_add_to_quotelist(url) {

```
jQuery('.ajax-loading-img').fadeIn();

jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'POST',

  url: url,

  data: jQuery('.cart').serialize(),

  success: function( response ) {

                var msg = jQuery('#dvin-message-popup');

                var loading = jQuery('.ajax-loading-img');

                loading.fadeOut();  

                response_arr = response.split("##");

                //if div exists, display count

                if(jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').length > 0) {

                    jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').html(response_arr[1]);

                }

                jQuery('.quotelistadd').css('display','none');

                jQuery('.quotelistaddedbrowse').css('display','block');

    }



});
```

}

//handles ajax call add to quotelist

function call_ajax_add_to_quotelist_from_shop(url,prod_id) {

```
jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.ajax-loading-img').fadeIn();

jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'POST',

  url: url,

  data: 'add-to-cart='+prod_id+'&action=add_to_qlist',

  success: function( response ) {

                var loading = jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.ajax-loading-img');

                loading.fadeOut();  

                response_arr = response.split("##");

                //if div exists, display count

                if(jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').length > 0) {

                    jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').html(response_arr[1]);

                }

                jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.quotelistadd').css('display','none');

                jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.quotelistaddedbrowse').css('display','block');

    }

});
```

}

//handles ajax call add to quotelist

function remove_item_from_shop(prod_id) {

```
jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'POST',

  url: add_to_quotelist_ajax_url,

  data: 'add-to-quotelist='+prod_id+'&action=remove',

  success: function( response ) {



                response_arr = response.split("##");

                //if div exists, display count

                if(jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').length > 0) {

                    jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').html(response_arr[1]);

                }



                jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.quotelistadd').css('display','block');

                jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.quotelistaddedbrowse').css('display','none');



                jQuery('#'+prod_id).children('.quotelistexistsbrowse').css('display','none');

    }

});
```

}

//handles ajax call post form

function call_ajax_submitform_to_admin(url) {

```
//if list has no products

if(jQuery('.dvin_no_prod_qlist').length >0){

    alert(empty_productlist_msg);

    return false;

}
```

jQuery('.ajax-loading-img').fadeIn();

```
jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'POST',

  url: url,

  data: jQuery('.qlist').serialize(),

  success: function( response ) {

                var msg = jQuery('#dvin-message-popup');

            var loading = jQuery('.ajax-loading-img');

                loading.fadeOut();  

                response_arr = response.split("##");

                if(response_arr[0]=='error'){

                    jQuery('#dvin_messages').html(response_arr[1]);

                }else {

                    jQuery('#dvin_wcql_details').css('display','none');

                    jQuery('#dvin_wcql_success_msg').css('display','block');

                    jQuery('#dvin_messages').html('&nbsp;');

                    jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                }



                msg.fadeIn();

                window.setTimeout(function(){

                   msg.fadeOut(); 

                }, 2000);

    }

});
```

}

//when variatioon_id changes, take appropriate action on quotelist button (show/hide)

jQuery('[name|="variation_id"]').change(function() {

```
if(jQuery('[name|="variation_id"]').val()!='') {



//find whether it is already exists in quotelist

    jQuery.ajax({

     type: 'POST',

        url: dvin_wcql_plugin_ajax_prodfind_url,

        data: 'prod_id='+jQuery('[name|="product_id"]').val()+'&variation_id='+jQuery('[name|="variation_id"]').val(),

        success: function( response ) {



            if(response == "true") {

                jQuery('.quotelistadd').css('display','none');

                jQuery('.quotelistexistsbrowse').css('display','block');

                jQuery('.quotelistaddedbrowse').css('display','none');

            } else {



                jQuery('.quotelistadd').css('display','block');

                jQuery('.quotelistexistsbrowse').css('display','none');

                jQuery('.quotelistaddedbrowse').css('display','none');

            }

        }



    });

    jQuery('.quotelistaddresponse').html('');

}



});
```

//handles Ajax request to remove item from list

function remove_item_from_dpage() {

```
jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'POST',

  url: add_to_quotelist_ajax_url+'?action=remove',

  data: jQuery('.cart').serialize(),

  success: function( response ) {



                response_arr = response.split("##");

                //if div exists, display count

                if(jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').length > 0) {

                    jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').html(response_arr[1]);

                }



                jQuery('.quotelistadd').css('display','block');

                jQuery('.quotelistaddedbrowse').css('display','none');

                jQuery('.quotelistexistsbrowse').css('display','none');

    }



});
```

}

//handles ajax request on removing product from quotelist

function remove_item_from_qlist(url,rowid) {

```
jQuery('#dvin_messages').html('&nbsp;');

jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'GET',

  url: url,

  success: function( response ) {

        if(rowid !=0) {

            jQuery("#"+rowid).remove(); 

            arr = response.split('##');

            jQuery('#dvin_message').html(arr[0]);



            //if div exists reflect the total count

            if(jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').length>0) {

                jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').html(arr[1]);

            }



            //display no products message, if exists

            if(arr[2]!='') {

                jQuery('.cart').append('<tr class="dvin_no_prod_qlist"><td colspan="6"><center>'+arr[2]+'</center></td></tr>'); 

            }

        }



        }



});
```

}

//handles ajax request on adding product to cart from quotelist

function add_tocart_fromqlist(url) {

```
jQuery('#dvin_messages').html('&nbsp;');

jQuery.ajax({

 type: 'GET',

  url: url,

  success: function( response ) {

        jQuery('#dvin_messages').html(response);

    }



});
```

}

//Update Message popup

jQuery.fn.center = function () {

this.css("position","absolute");

```
this.css("top", ((jQuery(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + 

                                            jQuery(window).scrollTop() + "px");

this.css("left", ((jQuery(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + 

                                            jQuery(window).scrollLeft() + "px");

return this;
```

}

//center the message popup

jQuery('#dvin-message-popup').center();

jQuery('.dvin_popup').center();

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

```
jQuery('#dvin-message-popup').center();
```

});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
//if list has some products

if(jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').length>0) {



    //if DIV for count exists, update it

    jQuery('#dvin-quotelist-count').html(dvin_quotelist_count);

}
```

});

I excuse for the bad editing but for now I am facing some problem to edit it too.
Thanks,

Aisha

Comment: well it will be nice if you added the action what takes care of the script.. other solution it will be to remove the action and place the code in another file and re add the action with your own file

Comment: Its not working even when i remove something it also does not work

Comment: are you sure that is not cache version?

Comment: yes because whenever I remove something or add something the file stops working. Cached versions always take code from cache and do not react to the changes immediately.

Comment: unless you post the related code there is nothing to do, also debug.log it will helpful

Comment: "yes because whenever I remove something or add something the file stops working" did you not say the file is not working anyway on the server? Your first port of call with js is to check the console on your browser for errors and then you can at least post the correct issue. The code above is using custom ajax functions on different urls so if its not caching, you might check these files also.

Comment: Also check the `wp_enqueue_script` reference. Many plugins will auto-minify scripts and serve the `script.min.js` version if a constant is not defined (such as `WP_DEBUG`). Locally you may have `WP_DEBUG` enabled which could trigger the possible loading of the regular script `script.js`. But if `WP_DEBUG` is false on the live server, you'd only ever view the minified version (which i assume you haven't changed).

Comment: I would strongly suggest using [`wp_deregister_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_script) and then enqueue your modified version, instead of hacking at a plugin.

Comment: until now nothing worked for me